# C# Linq exact part of collection

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble wording this question, but hopefully this makes sense. I can add more detail.

How can I use linq to check if `End` ids: `1, 2` are part of `TestTable` grouped by the `Start` column?  I want to check for each distinct list of `Start` contains a list of `End` that matches exactly.

So in this case if I'm checking if `End` ids `1, 2` exist, they do for `Start` `1`. If I'm checking if `1, 2, 5` exist in `End` ids, they wouldn't because none have the same `Start` id.

TestTable

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| Id        | Start   | End      |
+-----------+---------+----------+
|         1 | 1       | 1        |
|         2 | 1       | 2        |
|         3 | 2       | 5
|         4 | 2       | 1        |
|         5 | 3       | 2        |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Again, please let me know if I can add more detail. I want to check if  `End` contains a list of values that have the same `Start` Id.

**Adding more detail:** 
I know this will get me all the matching Ids

```
var matchingList = myTable.Where(x => myOtherList.Any(y => y.Id == x.End)).ToList()
```

but how can I get the matching ids by the `Start` id? `End` `1, 2` are exact matches for `Start` id `1`. That's what I'm after. I want to see if they are a exact subset by `Start`.

**Final Edit:** 
For a given set of End values I want to see if they exist (exactly) for a distinct Start value.

Comment: It would be nice to start from what you have tried so far...

Comment: So, what you want to know is: if, given a *list* of `End` values, which `Start` values that match that list. Is that right?

Comment: You said subset, so not an exact match, but rather includes (or in LINQ terms, _Contains_)?

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni that is correct. For a given list of `End` values I want to check if they already exist for a `Start` id. I want to to be an exact match of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestTableRow
{
    public TestTableRow(int id, int start, int end)
    {
        Id = id;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

public class TestTable
{
    private IList<TestTableRow> _rows = new List<TestTableRow>();

    public void AddRow(TestTableRow row)
    {
        _rows.Add(row);
    }

    // I'm assuming there can only be zero or 1 matches, otherwise this would need to be rewritten to return a list.
    public int? FindExactStart(params int[] requiredEndIds)
    {
        var groupings = _rows.GroupBy(x => x.Start);
        foreach (var grouping in groupings)
        {
            var actualEndIds = grouping.Select(x => x.End).ToList();
            // We need to check that all the actual ends are in the list, and that there are no others.
            if (actualEndIds.All(x => requiredEndIds.Contains(x)) && requiredEndIds.Except(actualEndIds).Any() == false)
            {
                return grouping.Key;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testTable = new TestTable();
        testTable.AddRow(new TestTableRow(1, 1, 1));
        testTable.AddRow(new TestTableRow(2, 1, 2));
        testTable.AddRow(new TestTableRow(3, 2, 5));
        testTable.AddRow(new TestTableRow(4, 2, 1));
        testTable.AddRow(new TestTableRow(5, 3, 2));

        var firstAnswer = testTable.FindExactStart(new[] { 1, 2 });
        Console.WriteLine("First answer: " + firstAnswer);

        var secondAnswer = testTable.FindExactStart(new[] { 1, 2, 5 });
        Console.WriteLine("Second answer: " + secondAnswer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the `TestTable` by `Start` so you can see which `End`s belong to each `Start`, then verify that set contains all of the test set of Ends:

```
var TestTable = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Start = 1, End = 1 },
    new { Id = 2, Start = 1, End = 2 },
    new { Id = 3, Start = 2, End = 5 },
    new { Id = 4, Start = 2, End = 1 },
    new { Id = 5, Start = 3, End = 2 },
};

var TestSet1 = new[] { 1, 2 };

var ans1 = TestTable.GroupBy(tt => tt.Start)
                    .Select(ttg => new { Start = ttg.Key, Ends = ttg.Select(tt => tt.End).ToList() })
                    .Where(StartEnds => TestSet1.All(StartEnds.Ends.Contains) && TestSet1.Count() == StartEnds.Ends.Count())
                    .Select(StartEnds => StartEnds.Start);
// ans1 is [1]

var TestSet2 = new[] { 1, 2, 5 };
var ans2 = TestTable.GroupBy(tt => tt.Start)
                    .Select(ttg => new { Start = ttg.Key, Ends = ttg.Select(tt => tt.End).ToList() })
                    .Where(StartEnds => TestSet2.All(StartEnds.Ends.Contains) && TestSet2.Count() == StartEnds.Ends.Count())
                    .Select(StartEnds => StartEnds.Start);
// ans2 is empty
```

If you have a `ToHashSet` extension, you may want to convert the `Ends` field to a `HashSet` if there is enough data to need the performance increase.

You don't have to have the `Select` in the query, that was to make it easier to understand, you can just search through the groups directly:

```
var ans15 = TestTable.GroupBy(tt => tt.Start)
                     .Where(ttg => ttg.All(tt => TestSet1.Contains(tt.End)) && TestSet1.Count() == ttg.Count())
                     .Select(ttg => ttg.Key);
// ans15 is [1]
```

Comment: This solution has a logic flaw. For example, try it with a TestSet with just "1" in it, it returns true but should return false. My solution works in that scenario.

Comment: Mine is returning the wrong answer anyway, it should return the matching starts. I wrote my answer based on the OP that said "subset" before it was corrected in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but if the query is ran against a database it will perform one request for each of the possible starts, which is a performance killer.

My alternative solution uses join on the array of required ends:

```
var availableStarts =
    from row in _rows
    group row.End by row.Start
    into g
    where (from end in g
                join requiredEnd in requiredEndIds on end equals requiredEnd
                select end).Count() == requiredEndIds.Length
          && g.Count() == requiredEndIds.Length
    select g.Key;
```

This solution relies on the fact that we want an exact match of the end id set and so we can join both lists and check if the count matches.

This query can translate to SQL directly and will return all results at once with one single query.